# Opencv installation error ubuntu 14.04

Tags: opencv, cmake, opencv3.0

I am trying to build OpenCV on Ubuntu 14.04 for ARM using [this guide](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/crosscompilation/arm_crosscompile_with_cmake.html). I have tried to install every package, but it is providing me these error on CMAKE.

```
checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' not found
checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' not found
checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' not found
checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' not found
checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' not found
Looking for linux/videodev.h
Looking for linux/videodev.h - found
Looking for linux/videodev2.h
Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
Looking for sys/videoio.h
Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
checking for module 'libavresample'
package 'libavresample' not found
Looking for libavformat/avformat.h    
Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
checking for module 'libgphoto2'
package 'libgphoto2' not found  
CMake Warning at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:54 (message):ICV: Local copy of ICV package has invalid MD5 hash:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e (expected:
8b449a536a2157bcad08a2b9f266828b)
Call Stack (most recent call first):3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:108 (_icv_downloader)cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:235 (include)cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)CMakeLists.txt:526 (include)
ICV: Downloading ippicv_linux_20141027.tgz...
CMake Error at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:71 (file):
file DOWNLOAD HASH mismatch for file: [/home/akash/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/ippicv/downloads/linux-8b449a536a2157bcad08a2b9f266828b/ippicv_linux_20141027.tgz]expected hash: [8b449a536a2157bcad08a2b9f266828b]actual hash: [d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e]
Call Stack (most recent call first):3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:108 (_icv_downloader)cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:235 (include)cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)CMakeLists.txt:526 (include)
CMake Error at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:75 (message):ICV: Failed to download ICV package: ippicv_linux_20141027.tgz.Status=7;"Couldn't connect to server"
Call Stack (most recent call first):3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:108 (_icv_downloader)cmake/OpenCVFindIPP.cmake:235 (include)cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:12 (include)CMakeLists.txt:526 (include)
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: I am sorry..its not very clear formatting..

Answer (score 0):

CMAKE complains about missmatching MD5 hashes.

> CMake Warning at 3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake:54 (message):ICV: Local copy of ICV package has invalid MD5 hash:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e (expected:
>   8b449a536a2157bcad08a2b9f266828b)

Since the hashes provided in [the cmake file](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/3rdparty/ippicv/downloader.cmake) are correct this may tell you that the downloaded package is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

try again with :

```
 cmake \
 -DOPENCV_ICV_URL="http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/3rdparty/ippicv"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can download ippicv_linux_20141027.tgz from the below link. and replace 
with 
/home/akash/Downloads/opencv-3.0.0/3rdparty/ippicv/downloads/linux-8b449a536a2157bcad08a2b9f266828b/ippicv_linux_20141027.tgz

Link:
http://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_opencvlibrary/downloads/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_linux_20141027.tgz/

Comment: BTW, the version linked here is too old as of today (won't build). At time of writing you need 20151201 - here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/tree/ippicv/master_20151201/ippicv